# Edit existing named region with openxlsx

Tags: r

I have an existing workbook with some data and charts.
I'm using `openxlsx` to add recent data and would like to edit an existing named range to reflect this (the charts use this named region).

I tried using `writeData` and `createNamedRegion` to do that, but I receive the error message "Error in (...): Named region with name 'named_region' already exists!"

```
library(openxlsx)
filename <- 'test.xlsx'
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = 'test')
writeData(wb, sheet='test', x=data.frame(a=1:3,b=2:4), startCol=1, startRow=1,
          colNames=T, rowNames=F, name='named_region')
saveWorkbook(wb, file=filename, overwrite=TRUE)

wb <- loadWorkbook(file = filename)
writeData(wb, sheet='test', x = data.frame(a=4:5,b=5:6),
          startRow=5, colNames=F, rowNames=FALSE, keepNA=FALSE) # ok

# not ok
# writeData(wb, sheet='test', x = data.frame(a=4:5,b=5:6),
#           startRow=5, colNames=F, rowNames=FALSE, keepNA=FALSE, name='named_region') 
# createNamedRegion(wb, sheet='test', cols=1, rows=2:6, name='named_region')

saveWorkbook(wb, file=filename, overwrite=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, and your question gave me the answer. You need to remove the named range that already exists : https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/NamedRegion.html

```
deleteNamedRegion(wb = wb, name = "named_region")
```